# Why is '-' equal to 0 (zero) in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, zero

When you run the following query in SQL Management studio the **result** will be **1**.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN '-' = 0 THEN 
        1 
    ELSE 
        0 
    END
```

That scares me a bit, because I have to check for **0** value a numerous number of times and it seems it is vulnerable for being equal to value **'-'**.

Comment: `-`  is unary minus.

Comment: `+` and `-` can be converted to `int`, even `ISNUMERIC('-')` returns 1. That is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx): _"ISNUMERIC returns 1 for some characters that are not numbers, such as plus (+), minus (-), and valid currency symbols such as the dollar sign ($)."_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking at it the wrong way around.

'-' is a string, so it will get implicitly casted to an integer value when comparing it with an integer:

```
select cast('-' as int) -- outputs 0
```

To make sure that you are actually comparing a value to the string '0', make your comparison like this instead:

```
select case when '-' = '0' then 1 else 0 end
```

In general, you're asking for trouble when you're comparing values of different data types, since [implicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) happen behind the scene - so avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains it clearly to me and provides solution.